# Changing KDE's mouse theme and buttons settings from a shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, kde, mouse, settings

I'm trying left handed mousing, and I want to be able to easily switch between right handed mode and left handed mode. There is a utility for Windows called [SwapMouseButtons](http://download.cnet.com/SwapMouseButtons/3000-2056_4-10053869.html) that allows to bind a key for that switch - both swapping the buttons and changing the pointer's direction.

I would like to do something similar for KDE in a shell script.

Swapping the buttons is easy with `xinput`, but I'm having a hard time changing the mouse theme to a left handed theme from the command line. I also prefer to find a KDE solution for the button swapping, as changes made via `xinput` are session-bound and KDE settings are saved. I wouldn't like to have a left handed theme with right handed buttons after a reset...

The problem is, I can't find much documentation on KDE's command line utilities. I found [this post](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=89951#p168680) that suggests using `kapplymousetheme`, which seems promising, but I can't figure out how to use it(no man page, no `--help` flag...)

I've also found that `kcmshell4 cursortheme` opens the mouse theme dialog, and that `kcmshell4` accepts the `--args` flag for sending arguments to the module, but I couldn't find nor figure out what arguments I need to send to just change the mouse theme without opening the dialog(if that's even supported).

I should also note that I want these changes to take effect immediately. Changing a configuration file and having to restart the system(or even just X or KDM) won't do, though if I can reload that configuration file(with a command line utility, of course) so that the changes will take effect immediately that will be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm fairly sure that changing KDE system settings from the command line [isn't possible generally](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=108974).

Comment: currently i am scripting my shortcuts and mouse settings for kde neon, which seems to work

Answer (score 5):

Two years late but I just re-solved this for Plasma 5. Maybe this will help the next person who comes along for this answer.

Here is a KDE method I use for swapping the mouse buttons around. Maybe the same thinking can be applied to altering the theme too.

Essentially, all you have to do is change MouseButtonMapping in `$HOME/.config/kcminputrc` between LeftHanded and RightHanded and then call `kcminit mouse`. Here is a script to do just this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=$HOME/.config/kcminputrc
CURRENT=`kreadconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key MouseButtonMapping`

if [ $CURRENT = "LeftHanded" ]; then
  kwriteconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key MouseButtonMapping RightHanded
elif [ $CURRENT = "RightHanded" ]; then
  kwriteconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key MouseButtonMapping LeftHanded
fi

kcminit mouse
```

Note that the file in KDE Plasma 4 is `$HOME/.kde/share/config/kcminputrc` and in Plasma 5 it is `$HOME/.config/kcminputrc` so you may have to edit the script to suit.

I then add this script to my main KDE apps menu so that I can assign a global hotkey for it.

**UPDATE 2018:**

Due to KDE config file changes the script now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=$HOME/.config/kcminputrc
CURRENT=`kreadconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded`

if [ $CURRENT = "true" ]; then
  kwriteconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded false
elif [ $CURRENT = "false" ]; then
  kwriteconfig --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded true
fi

kcminit mouse
```

**UPDATE 2022:**

kreadconfig and kwriteconfig are now kreadconfig5 and kwriteconfig5.

The kcminit command line has changed slightly.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=$HOME/.config/kcminputrc
CURRENT=`kreadconfig5 --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded`

echo $CURRENT

if [ $CURRENT = "true" ]; then
  kwriteconfig5 --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded false
  #/usr/bin/kdialog --title "Leftyswitch" --passivepopup "Right handed mouse" 3
elif [ $CURRENT = "false" ]; then
  kwriteconfig5 --file $CONFIG --group Mouse --key XLbInptLeftHanded true
  #/usr/bin/kdialog --title "Leftyswitch" --passivepopup "Left handed mouse" 3
fi

kcminit kcm_mouse
```

Comment: `kcminit kcm_mouse` does update the value in `~/.config/kcminputrc`, but doesn't actually switch the mouse buttons (USB-attached mouse - don't know if that's relevant). So I tried just **`kcminit`**, and that works for me (even though it looks like it's reinitializing some other things too)

Comment: As I understand it there have been bugs around kcminit recently. I believe `kcminit kcm_mouse` will eventually work again when the fixes trickle down into distros.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change to left-handed as follows:

```
 xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"
```

You can find the documentation on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

Answer (score 0):

actual names for the configuration can only be found in the source code it seems, i.e. https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/tree/d3c40a0582edbfa2674006e5a15e991a65f8f409/kcms/mouse/backends/x11

i was searching for what to do with the settings from `~/.config/kcminputrc`

if you use `libinput` (instead of `libevdev`) then you probably want to check `x11_libinput_dummydevice.h`, the last line of the 3-line-paragraphs (not the ones with 'supports' or 'default' in their property names) at the bottom will tell you what you want, if you're after mouse settings

apply these via running `kcminit`, which gives such output:

```
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_style.so"
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_fonts.so"
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"
kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_kgamma.so"
```